# How to properly unpack Protobuf Any type in PHP

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I'm desperately trying to check whether an "unknown" protobuf payload wrapped within an `Any` is some specific type (`Heartbeat`) and unpack it to a Heartbeat object using the code below. Both `Heartbeat` and `StatusChanged` are valid generated Protobuf classes.

```php
/* <external service> */
$event = (new StatusChanged)->setId("testId");

$any = new Any;
$any->pack($event);
$protobufBinaryAny = $any->serializeToString();
/* </external service> */

/* $protobufBinaryAny is the incoming binary data */
$anyEvent = new Any();
$anyEvent->mergeFromString($protobufBinaryAny);

if ($anyEvent->is(Heartbeat::class)) {
    $this->processHeartbeat($anyEvent->unpack());
} else {
   throw new UnknownMessageTypeException($anyEvent->getTypeUrl());
}
```

When running the following code, I'd expect it to throw a UnknownMessageTypeException, however, I get this:

```
Call to a member function getFullName() on null.
```

This error happens at `$data->is(Heartbeat::class)`, since the Heartbeat class obviously couldn't be found in the `DescriptorPool`.

```php
/**
 * Google\Protobuf\Any
 * https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/440a156e1cd5c783d8d64eef81a93b1df3d78b60/php/src/Google/Protobuf/Any.php#L315-L323
 */
class Any {
    public function is($klass)
    {
        $pool = \Google\Protobuf\Internal\DescriptorPool::getGeneratedPool();
        $desc = $pool->getDescriptorByClassName($klass);
        $fully_qualifed_name = $desc->getFullName();
        $type_url = GPBUtil::TYPE_URL_PREFIX.substr(
            $fully_qualifed_name, 1, strlen($fully_qualifed_name));
        return $this->type_url === $type_url;
    }
}
```

However, when explicitly initializing the Heartbeat before, it's working, since `Heartbeat` is now in the DescriptorPool.

```php
foreach ([
    \GPBMetadata\Heartbeat::class,
    \GPBMetadata\StatusChanged::class,
] as $klass) {
    $klass::initOnce();
}
```

But this manual initialization thing just feels wrong. Am I supposed to do it like that, or did I just miss a fancy autoloading-feature in the non-existing PHP docs?

For the time being, I wrote an autoloader for this case, but it still just feels not right:

```php
trait HandlesProtobufMessages
{
    function initializeProtobufMessages()
    {
        /** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader */
        $loader = require(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php');

        $classes = array_filter(array_keys($loader->getClassMap()), function ($className) {
            $namespace = "GPBMetadata\\";
            return substr($className, 0, strlen($namespace)) === $namespace;
        });

        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $class::initOnce();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you have more insights into this protobuf jungle and can help me out here, would be glad!

Thank you in advance